# URL Hack working for some fields but not others. Why?

Tags: urlhacking

This should have taken me 5 minutes and after 1.5 hours of trying different things I still can't seem to understand why this url hack doesn't work

The code below just pre-populates the 
1 contact
2 account
3 and the current user.

The first two work fine however the current user doesn't make it into the custom lookup field. I rechecked the ID of the field. It is correct. What am I missing?

```
/a07/e?RecordType=012w0000000iaZ9&nooverride=1&CF00N20000003NRbz={!Account.Name}&CF00N20000002kMy5_lkid={!Contact.Id}&CF00N20000002kMy5={!Contact.Name}&00Nw0000008ZPxv={!User.Name}&00Nw0000008ZPxv_lkid={!User.Id}
```

Comment: Always check the ID of the field by inspecting the generated HTML (Developer tools in browser, F12 in Chrome) so that you can be sure that you're using the correct Ids.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing CF prefix for the user field..

hope this will work

```
/a07/e?RecordType=012w0000000iaZ9&nooverride=1&CF00N20000003NRbz=
{!Account.Name}&CF00N20000002kMy5_lkid={!Contact.Id}&CF00N20000002kMy5=
{!Contact.Name}&CF00Nw0000008ZPxv={!User.Name}&CF00Nw0000008ZPxv_lkid=
{!User.Id}
```

Comment: What is it? Is there some meaning?